unable to use password from property file in mule 4
I am not able to use the below mentioned password from property file in mule4.
I am trying like ${db.password} and database connectivity is failing but hardcoded value is working fine. Is it because password contain colon and semicolon?
app.properties
db.host=test
db.port=1443
db.database=test_db
db.password=DAwrtkcz%35:\zC;

xml config not working:
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="af868fbb-3dc2-4392-9e8d-4195343e26d9" >
            <db:mssql-connection host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}" user="${db.user}" password="${db.password}" databaseName="${db.dbname}" />
    </db:config>

xml config working:
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="af868fbb-3dc2-4392-9e8d-4195343e26d9" >
            <db:mssql-connection host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}" user="${db.user}" password="DAwrtkcz%35:\zC;" databaseName="${db.dbname}" />
    </db:config>

gobal.xml
   <configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" doc:id="edb2306f-8ead-4bfc-8263-d78300b26ce7" file="properties\app.properties" />


What is your YAML? Did you wrap the password in quotes?

[edit] the question to add a [mre]. Be sure to include the Database connector configuration -as XML text, no images- and how the property file is configured. If there are any errors add them too. Use [code block] format for configurations, code and logs.

@HarshankBansal is .properties file not yaml

@aled I've added the xml config. Error is just connectivity failure. If i am passing hardcoded value in password it's working.

Where are you defining that property?

@aled other properly value like db.host, db.port,db.user those are working fine. issue is only with the db.password so please check that only. file is inside src/main/resource folder.

You haven't show how that properties file is configured in the application.

@aled please check the gobal.xml

@aled did you get a chance to look into issue.

@Devendra are you able to resolve this issue? what was the solution or workaround?

Maybe string password need to have a escape char to escape “\”. It would be like:
DAwrtkcz%35:\\zC;


Use a YAML format and wrap it with quote?
src/main/resources/properties/app-config.yaml
db:
  host: "test"
  port: "1443"
  database: "test_db"
  password: "DAwrtkcz%35:\zC;"

global.xml
<configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" doc:id="edb2306f-8ead-4bfc-8263-d78300b26ce7" file="properties\app.yaml" />

